# Divide Operation in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

I'm working on a ssrs report, they want to see below result
[Sample Output][1]
that is the final row in the report and I want to get % value by dividing 558 with 388 in above pic.

This is what I'm designed in ssrs
[Report Design][2]
highlighted one contains below formula:

```
=( Sum(Fields!Male.Value + Fields!Female.Value ) / (Sum(Fields!Male.Value,  "GradeCode" ) + Sum(Fields!Female.Value,  "GradeCode" ) ) )
but I'm getting 100% instead of 70%.
Below are the columns I have GradeCode, Male count, female count, race.
Can someone please suggest me the correct formula?
this is the expected result [enter image description here][3]
This is my design [enter image description here][4]
This is my result [enter image description here][5]
I highlighted the last row in that I should get the result of 18/582 instead it is giving 100% (in the pic I just displayed value in % and the denominator is not present)



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB9Lz.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMc6f.png
```

Comment: Put sum values into individual text boxes and check what are the value comes. Then you can identify what is an actual issue. In my understanding use column group scope in `sum(field,"column group name")`.

Comment: I used column group scope, for numerator it is showing correct value for column group. where as for denominator I supposed to get total value (Male + Female) irrespective of group. currently this is not working for me. If I place row group in the denominator Sum function I'm getting out of scope error. For Ex: column group has a total of 18 and total count is 508 then I supposed to get 18/508 = 3.54%, but I'm seeing as 100% it is calculating 18/18 which is wrong.

Comment: Here is the formula I used : =Sum((Fields!Male.Value + Fields!Female.Value), "Federal_Race_Group") / (Sum(Fields!Male.Value ) + Sum(Fields!Female.Value ) )

Comment: Check below answer, it will help to get grand total value by using dataset name in group scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use DataSet Name into group scope.

e.g

```
=Sum((Fields!Male.Value + Fields!Female.Value), "Federal_Race_Group") / (Sum(Fields!Male.Value,"DataSetName" ) + Sum(Fields!Female.Value,"DataSetName" ) )
```

Check my report preview. I have used sample dataset.

[image: Report Design]

[image: Report Preview]

Comment: As you mentioned your E.g. 18/505 calculation taken 18/18. So that I created sample report based on your report design. It’s ok, can you share your report with sample data. If possible I will clear your issue. Thanks..

Comment: I just posted my given expected results and what I'm getting from my design.

Comment: I checked all the images. It will work with my solution. You can add denominator value to "DataSet1" name in sum(...,"DataSet1").